# How to locate the element correctly to click on href element in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How do I write an xpath so that I can click on the settings button with selenium in python for the following html. Clicking the element is made harder by the fact that the settings element doesn't have an own id.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#editor">Structure</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#feedback">Feedback</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#settings">General settings</a>
    </li>
```

I have tried multiple commands, but I don't seem to get it right.

I am using elements (plural) so that I can see if it matches any xpaths. Figured it would be the cleanest way to test out different xpaths. If I get the xpath correctly I will use element (singular) and add .click() to the end. I have tried at least these following codes.

1. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='nav nav-tabs']//*[href='#settings']")`
   --> return [] (xpath doesn't match?)
2. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class, 'nav-tabs')]")`
   --> returns []
3. `driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@href='#settings']")`
   --> return []

When I 'click' the element, it usually gives the following error message:

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//a[@href='#settings']"}
```

Comment: Have you tried CSS selector?

Comment: _driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href='#settings']").click()_
returns
_NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href='#settings']"}_

Do you have any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: Try using `WebDriverWait` see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

@MosheSlavin was close. However, to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "General settings"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.nav.nav-tabs li>a[href$='settings']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='nav nav-tabs']//li/a[text()='General settings']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: The problem turned out to be, not that the element hadn't loaded, but that selenium was looking for the element in the wrong frame. The link you provided helped me find the information needed to solve the problem. So thank you very much for that! So the solution was to find the right iframe id and insert it in this function _driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")_ . After that I ran driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@href='#settings']").click() and it worked. :)

Comment: @TomasStorås It's not only you, everyone starting with _Selenium_ have to cross these phases, so while answering I always point the _New contributors_ to the detailed answer which I have published long back. Glad to be able to help you out.

Comment: This is an example of why it's a good idea to show the full HTML/URL in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The element might not be loaded yet, so use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the element:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#settings']")))
```

Or

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#settings']")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven't defined a class, so I suppose I should not include self in the code(?). Well I ran it like this: _WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='#settings']")))_
And it returned: _raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) TimeoutException_

I don't believe the problem to be that the element has not loaded. Since I have the webpage open and keep running different commands at it, so the element should definitely have loaded. Could it be that it is invisible (!?) somehow.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was that selenium was looking for the element in the wrong frame. I inspected the html code and found two iframe id's. I inserted one of the iframe id's in this function

```
driver.switch_to.frame("iframe_name")
```

and then

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@href='#settings']").click()
```